# Automating a logstash configuration changes

Tags: elasticsearch, github, logstash, devops

I'm looking for a solution to automate a logstash `filter` change.

I'm hosting the logstash configuration code in git and every change requires a code change, PR, merge and deployment of logstash.

In my use-case, I need to change the logstash configuration for a few hours and I'm looking for a solution to automate this process or exporting the configuration out of logstash `filter` file, so it will be looking for example at a shared file I'd be able to change with schedule task.

what is the right way to do it? or maybe if you have any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to configure Logstash to [periodically reload](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/reloading-config.html) the configuration files, by configuring the following settings in `logstash.yml`:

```
config.reload.automatic: true
config.reload.interval: 10s
```

Comment: thanks, what is the right way to schedule a change in github? (commit+push)

Comment: That's independent from Logstash and the subject of another question I'd say. let's close this one if it helped